# Cant find mysql module in python program

Tags: python, mysql

I've created a program in python which utilizes a connection to a mySQL server. The program has been created in PyCharm and works perfectly there, however when I try to run the file normally as the .py file, it cannot find the module named mysql.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\razer\PycharmProjects\Project\newcustomer.py", line 5, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'`

Any idea on why this module cannot be found? All of the modules are installed on my system

Comment: Perhaps PyCharm is using a different Python environment than your console, from which you are running your `.py` file.

Comment: I checked this, python was infact running 3.8 on pycharm but 3.7.6 on windows, however the output is still the same.

Comment: So this suggests `mysql` is installed in your 3.8 env but not your 3.7.  I suggest running the script in the same env as you developed it.  So switch your console to the 3.8 env and try again.